# How to convert Atom to RSS?

Tags: perl, rss, atom-feed

I've been searching around for a way to convert an Atom feed to an RSS feed. I tried atom2rss but it only gave me the first paragraph or so of the document, then truncated it. Is there any way I could get a perl script to use the Atom and RSS libraries to convert between the two?

Answer (score 5):

Obligatory "why would anyone want to do that": Atom is a real Internet standard, with a [published IETF RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287), the same sort of documents that regulate the rest of the Internet. [RSS is an incompatible mess.](http://web.archive.org/web/20110726001954/http://diveintomark.org/archives/2004/02/04/incompatible-rss)

Atom is sanely extensible, and indeed it does have fine extensions like [AtomPub](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023) and [threading](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4685). The times of RSS-only feed readers is long over, so dual-publishing is not necessary anymore, just publish Atom feeds and you're set.

But if you do not care about that and have a job to finish, [XML::Feed](http://p3rl.org/XML::Feed) offers conversion as part of its API (code untested), thoroughly [validate](http://feedvalidator.org) what you are going to get as output:

```
my $atom = XML::Feed->parse(URI->new('http://example.com/atom.xml'));
my $rss = $atom->convert('RSS');
print $rss->as_xml;
```

Comment: I need to convert it because Wordpress doesn't support importing from Atom, only RSS. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I tried it out, but it escapes all html tags. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Atom's standardness is exactly why it's such a good over-the-line format. And RSS is what you can use for hacks and chewing gum. Converting RSS to Atom would be finicky and error prone. We want our upstream data in Atom, neat, orderly, wonderful. And from there we can convert and mash and mix as we please.